# Blender2.78 Rig- 1.not return to rest 2."G" rotates 3. Axes problem

Tags: rigging

re Rig Blender 2.78:

Followed the steps in the CGCookie Intro to Character Modeling Tutorial 2010 to make a rig, initially only on the Left side then to mirror the rig across the X axis.

Two problems that I have been unable to resolve even though I re-did the rig multiple times and then re-mirrored it several times.

The step that was done differently, or actually in addition to, the CG cookie tutorial was to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to align axes in the unilateral (Left side only) rig.  In the tutorial, in a prior version of Blender, *Z axis up* was selected.  For 2.78 there were so many options to chose for the axes.  I could not find information on how to decide which axis option to select. *Global Z axis* positive was consistently selected each time to make the Z axis up.

Problems in the unilateral rig (L side only) and also in the mirrored rig:

a. **Rig not return to rest position**                                      In Pose Mode, the clavicle and humerus/Upper arm 'fell' lower on Z axis and anterior on Y axis with the elbow bent out, and the lower arm following the deformation

Despite <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and even multiple tabbing into and out of Edit Mode, the rig did not return to the rest pose which was still visible in Edit Mode.  If I clicked *Rest Mode* the rig returned to the rest position, and yet when *Pose Mode* was clicked, the rig clavicle and arm returned to the fallen and anterior position

b. <kbd>**G**</kbd> key not work for clavicle, arm, hand, finger bones  (also for femur/thigh bone; although does work for some bones ex Spine)

When <kbd>G</kbd> pushed, the bone ROTATES as if <kbd>R</kbd> had been selected.  When <kbd>R</kbd> is typed, the bone rotates as would be expected.  In other words, **<kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> result in the same action.**

**In the initial Rig prior to ANY intervention these same bones responded the same way when <kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> are typed**

c. Unable to manually fix this                                      When select and try to reposition clavicle/shoulder or humerus/upper arm or forearm or fingers... not able to move the bone into the desired position (because the bone Rotates even when <kbd>G</kbd> typed)

d. tried to *normalize* axes to fix the problem -> didn't help
    When the *Meta-rig (human)* was added to the scene, it was upright and thus did not need to be rotated to align with the mesh so the axes on the rig were as per the initial armature.          However for reasons a, b,  and c , thought perhaps the problem was the axes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>-> selected *Global Z Axis* positive to *normalize* the axes.  The axis became Z up (initially it was pointing laterally)

Question 2:
 Any suggestions for how to mirror the axes for the rig after the rig is X mirrored (Blender 2.78)?

On the Left side, the fingers Z axis points up and the X axis points medially towards the thumb.  After X mirror (<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>)  and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, Global Z axis positive, the R side fingers Z axis points up but the X axis points laterally towards the pinky.  Tried every possible axis option yet wasn't able to point X axis medially on the right while maintaining Z axis pointing up.

(Rig was mirrored across the X axis per CGCookie Tutorial:

1. *Edit Mode*
2. Select all armature not in center
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to reset cursor
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>-> Right click -> <kbd>.</kbd>-> <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>-1</kbd>to flip around cursor
5. now flip the names; currently all names 'L.001'
   a. <kbd>W</kbd>
   b. click *Flip Names*-> all 'L.001' rename to R
6. In the tutorial, the axes mixed up 
   To fix:
   a. Select all the <kbd>R</kbd> Duplicated bones
   b. enable (check) *X-Axis Mirror* on L Tool Panel                               (*Armature Tools*-> *Armature Options*-> *X-Axis Mirror*)
   c. <kbd>G</kbd> Esc to flip some axes)

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is a lot of text! Maybe try to make it a bit more concise or summarize the questions at the beginning or end of your question.

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question per post. You are welcome to ask as many separate questions as you need.

Comment: B"H The 1 question is how to fix the rig.  The details were to explain the problem.

Comment: B"H Rig did NOT able to translate to rest position even after:
1 Manipulate Center Point OFF
2 changed from BBones to octahedrons-Confirmed direction of head and tail were correct.
3 UpArm bone- unchecked Inherit rot, scale, local; Parent (shoulder) deleted   
4 Pose Mode locations and rotations ALL unlocked
5 locations per Edit Mode typed into Pose Mode
6 ElbowTarget moved- helped but still NOT in rest position  Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you!!